# Fast auto-reconnect under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, ethernet, pppoe, connection

I have an ubuntu up to date with wired Internet connection, but if I enter the Network Connections at the Wired tab it says that I have eth1 and eth0, and they're never used.

The system connects automatically to the Internet after booting, but if it disconnects for some reason I can not reconnect, only if I reset it in the terminal all over again (sudo pppoeconf)

Is there a quick reconnecting method?

Answer (score 1):

You could try (in a terminal): `sudo dhclient`

If your router's acting up, it might be faster