# Ubuntu 10.04 says wired network disconnected, but it works

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ethernet, notifications

I've installed ubuntu 10.04, hoping to get rid of the 9.10 errors. (Nvidia driver didn't work quite properly, had some problems with clicking in flash, and I had -and still have- wired network working, but ubuntu said that it's disconnected)
So the Nvidia driver is better now, but the network error is the same. I still have a working wired network connection, but when it starts says that it is disconnected. Notification area tells me the same thing.
Why is that?

Comment: Hardware specs would be nice.

Comment: cpu: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.26GHz, 2275 MHz
network:
  eth0                 ASUSTeK NX1001
  eth1                 VIA VT6102 [Rhine-II]

Comment: I have one network card on-board, but it didn't work for a while so I bought another one. After that I've installed a Windows XP and ubuntu 9.10. Ubuntu recognized the on-board card first and I couldn't get it work, because in the notification area somehow I got two of the volume controls instead of one network manager and if I started it from the system menu it said that I have eth0 and eth1(never used), but I had connection for a while (??). So I removed from BIOS the on-board one. Don't know why it recognizes it.

Comment: I had this problem first:
http://superuser.com/questions/113784/fast-auto-reconnect-under-ubuntu